# Spark -- convert date string in format of dd-MMM-YY to timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse a csv file with content like below into dataframe:

```
+------+---------+----------+
|Symbol|     Date|ClosePrice|
+------+---------+----------+
| SREEL| 1-Jan-14|     298.0|
| SREEL| 2-Jan-14|     299.9|
+------+---------+----------+
```

But I am unable to convert the date field into timestamp field as per give code snippet. It is giving me improper result.

Can anyone help me to understand reason for the same?

```
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TimeSeriesForecast").setMaster("local")
    sparkConf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
    val stockDF: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("data/Sreeleathers_Share_Price.csv")

    val priceDF: DataFrame = stockDF.select(stockDF("Symbol").as("Symbol"),
      stockDF("Date").as("Date"),
      stockDF("Close Price").as("ClosePrice"))

    //priceDF.printSchema
    //priceDF.show

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val finalDf: DataFrame = priceDF
      .withColumn("Price", priceDF("ClosePrice").cast(DoubleType))
      .withColumn("TimeStamp", unix_timestamp($"Date","d-MMM-yy").cast(TimestampType))
      .drop("Date").drop("ClosePrice")
      .sort("TimeStamp")
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Can you please update

Comment: @AnuragSharma... output is something like 1970-01-17 07:11:...

Answer (score 0):

I tried following in spark 1.6, It seem to be working. Posting answer as it is too long for a comment

```
val myDF = Seq(("1-Jan-14", 2, 1L), ("2-Jan-14", 1, 2L)).toDF("Date", "col2", "col3")
myDF.show()
+--------+----+----+
|    Date|col2|col3|
+--------+----+----+
|1-Jan-14|   2|   1|
|2-Jan-14|   1|   2|
+--------+----+----+

myDF.withColumn("TimeStamp", unix_timestamp($"Date","d-MMM-yy").cast(TimestampType)).show()
+--------+----+----+--------------------+
|    Date|col2|col3|           TimeStamp|
+--------+----+----+--------------------+
|1-Jan-14|   2|   1|2014-01-01 00:00:...|
|2-Jan-14|   1|   2|2014-01-02 00:00:...|
+--------+----+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: @ShashiShankar Which version of spark are you using? It will be good if you can post the output of the above two statements in the question itself. Will take a look.

Comment: Does the function works on windows env? I am facing issue with intellij but same is working fine on cygwin terminal.

Comment: @ShashiShankar    Looks like some issue with the windows environment maybe unix_timestamp() function